# Qt: QListWidget separator line between items?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I can't find any way to put a line between items in my list. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A style sheet would be easiest, for example:

```
myListWidget->setStyleSheet( "QListWidget::item { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }" );
```

You'll want to look at some of the [style sheet documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/stylesheet-examples.html)

Comment: Ah beautiful. I missed this in the documentation. That's kind of a real nice feature.

Answer (score 2):

2 improvements to the accepted answer:

1. Use the color palette of the widget to achieve a uniform look across different systems.
2. It is necessary to restore the `item:selected` style when restyling `item`

E.g. like this:

```
const auto & palette = tableWidget.palette();
tableWidget.setStyleSheet(QString("QListWidget::item { border-bottom: 1px solid %1; } QListWidget::item:selected { background-color: %2; color: %3; }")
    .arg(palette.midlight().color().name(),
         palette.highlight().color().name(),
         palette.highlightedText().color().name()));
```

Here you can see that the separator lines and selection color fit the default style of the widget:

[image]