# Qt: QListWidget separator line after particuler items?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

This is related to [Qt: QListWidget separator line between items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780411/qt-qlistwidget-separator-line-between-items#) 
But this above answer adds separator line after each items, I would like to know a way to add the separator line after particular items.

Comment: I don't think that stylesheet trick will apply here. Have you considered adding a special items as separators? Those items would need to have defined the `setSizeHint()`, so their height is small and also the `setFlags()` should define `Qt::NoItemFlags`, so the item is not selectable, etc. Oh, and you need to find out the way to draw a horizontal line in the item ;) Maybe try with `QListWidget::setItemWidget()` and put the `QFrame` there which has a shape set to `QFrame::HLine`.

Comment: Yeah, I like this idea. Let me try this, thanks for the suggestion.
And in the answer I guess @KaxukiCP confuesd it with "particular list widget" rather then the same widget and after a particular item.

Comment: @Googie Thanks for the suggestion. It worked :) 
You should add it as an answer.

However, I have one more small query - see if you can help here.
I want to add some gap on each sides of this separator line/frame. How can I achieve this, any pointer would be very helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a `QListWidgetItem` representing the separator. Such item would need to have defined the `setSizeHint()`, so its height is small, and also the `setFlags()` should define `Qt::NoItemFlags`, so the item is not selectable, etc. Then, after adding the item to the `QListWidget`, place a `QFrame`, with its shape set to `QFrame::HLine`, as the item's widget (using `QListWidget::setItemWidget()`).

As for your additional question from the comment, which is:

> I want to add some gap on each sides of this separator line/frame. How can I achieve this?

The only solution that comes to my mind right now is to embed the `QFrame` inside of another `QWidget` and put the `QWidget` as item's widget (remember that you need to add a layout manager to the `QWidget` in order to embed anything in it). Then set proper margins on the widget: `QWidget::setContentsMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`

Comment: Also to disable hovering of separator item add 
ui->listWidget->setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item:disabled { background: transparent; }");

Answer (score 1):

I found another possibility and tested it this time :p
You could create a new class inheriting QStyledItemDelegate that look like this :

```
void MyStyledItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);

    // I have decided to use Qt::UserRole + 1 to store my boolean
    // but it could be any other role while it's value is bigger than Qt::UserRole
    QVariant isSeparator = index.data(Qt::UserRole + 1);
    if (isSeparator.isValid() && isSeparator.toBool())
    {
        QRect rct = option.rect;
        rct.setY(rct.bottom() - 1);
        painter->fillRect(rct, QColor::fromRgb(qRgb(0, 0, 0)));
    }
}
```

And the for each QListWidgetItem you can do the following :

```
// Qt::UserRole + 1 => Must match the role set in the delegate
item->setData(Qt::UserRole + 1, true);
```

Install the custom in your QListWidget like this

```
listWidget->setItemDelegate(new MyStyledItemDelegate());
```

It will draw a black line under the text of the item if the Qt::UserRole + 1 is set to true.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the same trick with dynamic properties.

```
myListWidget->setStyleSheet( "QListWidget::item[separator="true"] { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }" );
```

And on the widget you want the line to be drawn :

```
myWidget->setProperty("separator", true);
```

However be carefull the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) says :

> Warning: If the value of the Qt property changes after the style sheet has been set, it might be necessary to force a style sheet recomputation. One way to achieve this is to unset the style sheet and set it again.

Comment: This will apply separator under every item of the list widget. Question is how to apply separators under particular items in the very same list widget.

Comment: There is a subtle difference, in the sylesheet I add a property selector. On each widget it will check if the property "separator" as a true value. If not or the property does not exist the style shouldn't be applied.

Comment: There are 2 errors in this solution: 1. You are setting property for the entire list widget, not its particular items. 2. Items in `QListWidget` (`QListWidgetItem`) are not a `QObject` and so they cannot hold dynamic properties.

Comment: @KazukiCP I want to add separator line depending upon each item's content, not each widget.

Comment: Oops, Googie is right. 
I forgot about the fact that QListWidgetItem isn't QObject. 
Should have test before posting >_<